# How to list last 7 days records in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

[image: SELECT * FROM dummy WHERE entry_date between current_date and current_date at time zone 'UTC' - interval '7 days';]

I want to display current date and previous 7 days. the query doesnt work for me.

```
SELECT * FROM dummy
 WHERE entry_date  between current_date  and current_date at time zone 'UTC' - interval '7 days
```

Comment: Please elaborate on `doesnt work for me`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i want to display the records from entry_date column where condition range is between current date and previous 7 days

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I doubt you have *future* entry dates.  So don't use `between`.  Instead:

```
where entry_date >= current_date at time zone 'UTC' - interval '7 days'
```

Note:  If you want to count the current date as a day, then you want `interval '6 days'`.

Answer (score 1):

`between` must specify *low* to *high*, but you have done the reverse (current date is greater than the date 7 days ago).

Reverse the parameters given to `between`:

```
where entry_date between current_date at time zone 'UTC' - interval '7 days and current_timestamp
```

Also note changed the "high" range to end with `current_timestamp` not `current_date`, because `current_date` is the previous midnight, but you want everything up to "now".

Comment: thanks but it doesnt display current date

Comment: sounds like you have timezone issues. try `between ... and current_timestamp`

Answer (score -2):

WITH CTE_Weekday(DayNumber,
[DayName],
DayDate )
AS (SELECT 7,
DATENAME(weekday, GETDATE()) AS [DayName],
CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS [DayDate]
UNION ALL
SELECT DayNumber - 1,
DATENAME(weekday, DATEADD(day, DayNumber, GETDATE())) AS [DayName],
DATEADD(Day, DayNumber, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) AS [DayDate]
FROM CTE_Weekday
WHERE DayNumber > 1)
SELECT DayNumber,
[DayName],
DayDate
FROM CTE_Weekday

Comment: Please Add your tableName and ColumnName in CTE, You will get your required result.

Comment: This is invalid for Postgres

Comment: Please consider to read the article "how to answer" of SO: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Okay, I will b e careful next time