# How to get an accurate number of results when selecting records from a period of time

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a problem very similar to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65193855/how-to-list-last-7-days-records-in-postgresql) in that I need a full seven days of records.  My query looks something like this:

```sql
  SELECT id, entry_timestamp
    FROM entries
   WHERE created_on >= TO_DATE('2023-01-25', 'YYYY-MM-DD') at time zone 'UTC' - interval '7 days'
ORDER BY entry_timestamp
```

In my table `entry_timestamp` is a "timestamp without timezone" column and `created_on` is a "date" column.

(I need the `TO_DATE()` instead of `current_date` because I need to be able to specify a particular date)

When I run that query I get results with `entry_timestamp` from the last six days.

If I change it to `interval '8 days'` I get **ten** days for some reason.

What am I missing that is causing such a broad miscalculation?

Comment: 1) You don't need `to_date`, `'2023-01-25'::date` will work just find. 2)  `'2023-01-25'::date` when being compared to a `timestamp` becomes `select  '2023-01-25'::timestamp; 01/25/2023 00:00:00`. So to get a full 7 days do `select  '2023-01-24'::timestamp;`

Comment: Thanks for the info about `::date`.  However, changing my query to `created_on >= '2023-01-25'::date at time zone 'UTC' - interval '7 days'` gives me nine days instead of ten. Using `'2023-01-25'::timestamp` gives the same results.

Comment: Without some example data and expected output added to the question there is not much more that can be said or done.

Comment: I can see at least 2 elements that could cause the issue your are observing. First, you select `entry_timestamp` whereas your filter on `created_on`, with no guarantee the 2 are correlated. Second, your filter is only for dates later than a value you define, instead maybe of a `BETWEEN`. If I were you, I would execute `SELECT MIN(created_on), MAX(created_on), MIN(entry_timestamp), MAX(entry_timestamp) FROM entries WHERE created_on >= [whatever date you think returns incorrect results]` and see if all 4 values are what you expect.

Comment: Thanks, @Atmo! That actually helped me see the solution.  Your comment, combined with @Adrian-klaver's comment, I realized I needed this simple clause: `AND  entry_timestamp >= '2023-01-26'::date - interval '7 days' AND  entry_timestamp <= '2023-01-26'::date`

Comment: Happy to have helped. If I may give a piece of advice for the future: you should sometimes pause and think "could a simple date comparison fail in a popular software like postgresql". When you realize it could not, it allows you to rule out a lot of things to investigate, basically, you **know** before you even start the issue is in your query, not in postgresql, and especially not on functions/operators on dates (`TO_DATE`, `>=` absolutely always work). -> That meant I could focus on only the first half of your query.